# App Engine missing resources Basic Scaling

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cron

Right after deploying my code to App Engine cron jobs run fine. 10 hours later, at night I start getting issues like NoClassDefFound or IllegalArgumentException that both point out missing resources like the JAVA class residing in the project being deployed or property from .properties files (which is deployed as well). The same processes run fine for the first X hours and then suddenly give such errors.

I use Basic Scaling and I wonder whether this issue can relate to that type of scaling like not having the proper warmup (via warmup requests) like when using Automatic Scaling?
Any other ideas why VM cannot access resources at some point in time while some hours before same cron job ran fine without any redeployment/change in code?

Stack Traces:

````
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing required value for [public abstract java.lang.String org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions.getProject(), "Project id. Required when running a Dataflow in the cloud. See https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/projects for further details."]. 
    at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:440)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsValidator.validate(PipelineOptionsValidator.java:99)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsValidator.validate(PipelineOptionsValidator.java:50)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor283.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:217)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:155)```

Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/../../MyClass
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$NotAsync.service(ServletHolder.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1656)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at com.insightos.contact.filter.ContactSyncFilter.doFilter(ContactSyncFilter.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at com.insightos.apps.bf.servlet.InitializerFilter.doFilter(InitializerFilter.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.ParseBlobUploadHandler.handle(ParseBlobUploadHandler.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppEngineWebAppContext.doHandle(AppEngineWebAppContext.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.RpcConnection.handle(RpcConnection.java:270)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.RpcConnector.serviceRequest(RpcConnector.java:99)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty94.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:184)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchServletRequest(RequestRunner.java:264)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.dispatchRequest(RequestRunner.java:229)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestRunner.run(RequestRunner.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:273)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
````

Comment: Are you facing [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69456729/18265570)?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have 404 response code for the /_ah/start request.